# I been trying to make a piano application on android studio but when i run the application it show error and the application is not even opening?

Tags: android

I been trying to make a piano application on android studio but when i run the application it show error in line 16  here is my code 
 Please help me 
the error is something like this  :____-

> ---at com.example.user.piano.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button1,button2,button3,button4,button5,button6,button7,button8,button9,button10,button11;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button1=findViewById(R.id.bt1);
        button2=findViewById(R.id.bt21);
        button3=findViewById(R.id.bt31);
        button4=findViewById(R.id.bt41);
        button5=findViewById(R.id.bt51);
        button6=findViewById(R.id.bt61);
        button7=findViewById(R.id.bt71);
        button8=findViewById(R.id.bt81);
        button9=findViewById(R.id.bt91);
        button10=findViewById(R.id.bt101);
        button11=findViewById(R.id.bt111);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                music("one");
            }
        });
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                music("two");
            }
        });
        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                music("three");
            }
        });
        button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                music("four");
            }
        });
        button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                music("five");
            }
        });
        button6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                music("six");
            }
        });
        button7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                music("seven");
            }
        });
        button8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                music("eight");
            }
        });
        button9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                music("nine");
            }
        });
        button10.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                music("ten");
            }
        });
        button11.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                music("thirteen");
            }
        });

    }public void music(String args){
        int musicid =getResources().getIdentifier(args,"raw", "com.example.user.piano");


        MediaPlayer obj=MediaPlayer.create(this,musicid);
        obj.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should share complete error stack trace

Comment: There are some troubleshooting instructions under [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` twice.

Remove the `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` which is after `setContentView()`.